# Is there a way to see all the abilities of a unit?

Tags: civilization-5

The abilities of a unit can be seen in its "unit card" when it is selected as small icons, and I can hover over them for information. However, in late game many units (especially ones upgraded from old units) get so many abilities from promotions, buildings and social policies that the icons extend so much left they go under the unit icon and even flow off the screen, preventing me from hovering over them.

Is there are way to see what those abilities are? Perhaps there's a UI mod to change this?

Comment: I find this pretty annoying as well, but also, I wonder if there  is an obvious way to examine the upgrades of enemy units? The upgrade *icons* appear when their card does when you "prepare" the attack and are shown the expected outcome, but that the icons be examined to see what they are (obviously less of an issue in the future when I can remember which icon is which...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some mod-browsing, I've found a mod called **"All Promotions description tooltip"**. It adds a tooltip when hovering over a unit's icon in the bottom-left (its symbolic icon, not its painted portrait), which nicely lists **all** the promotions and their effects.

Before:

[image: before]

When hovering over that orange Frigate icon:

[image: after]

So this solved the problem for me, and I highly recommend this mod.

Answer (score 3):

The unfortunate answer seems to be, in my experience, no - there is no way to view all those icons to find out what icon number seventeen is.  Until a patch improves this, that seems to be the answer.